# Is there a tool for viewing an activity stream for a TFS project?

Tags: tfs

I am looking for a tool that displays various project activities for a given duration (say since yesterday) in the order that they took place e.g.

1. 9:40  "Dev 1" committed change set 12345
2. 9:43  "Dev 1" closed work item 2145
3. 10:05 "Dev 2" added a new work item 23456 "Design UI for customer details"
4. 10:25 "Dev 1" added comments to work item 23456
5. 10:45 "Dev 3" added work item 23456 to iteration 1
6. .
7. .

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it will give you exactly what you need with regards to a single rollup report but give [Sidekick](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/) a try.  We find it indispensable for getting a view into TFS.